# ubuntu 14.04 flash drive install not booting unless UEFI

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Im trying to install ubuntu 14.04(x64) from a usb flash drive but it doesn't boot unless the computer is in UEFI mode and i'm wondering if it is possible to install ubuntu in a computer that doesn't support UEFI

Comment: It is possible. In what way does it not work when you are on a non uefi mode?

Comment: all i get is a black screen and then nothing it only responds to crtl alt del to reboot, however i use the same flash drive in UEFI and works like a charm

Comment: How did you format the USB drive? Ensure it's a FAT32

Comment: formated to FAT 32, used rufus with the "MBR partition type for BIOS and UEFI computers" option, also tried unetbootin, same exact problem

Comment: weird thing guys the problem was the flash drive, i was using a 8 GB "Kingston DataTraveler 2.0", then i switch to a 8G kingston G3 and it worked just fine, problem solved, i guess i'll have to figure out what's wrong with the defective flash drive, worked one way and not the other. Thanks for the awnsers

Answer (score 1):

weird thing guys the problem was the flash drive, i was using a 8 GB "Kingston DataTraveler 2.0", then i switch to a 8G kingston G3 and it worked just fine, problem solved, i guess i'll have to figure out what's wrong with the defective flash drive, worked one way and not the other. 
Thanks for the answers